# How do websites like torrentz.eu collect their content?

Tags: search, web, search-engine, business-intelligence

I would like to know how some search website get their content.
I have used in the title the example of 'torrentz.eu' because it has content from several sources. 
I would like to know what is behind this system; do they 'simply' parse all the website they support and then show the content? Or using some web service? Or both?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are looking for the [Crawling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_crawler) aspect of [Information Retrieval](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information_retrieval).

Basically crawling is: Given an initial set `S` of websites, try to expand it by exploring the links (Find the [transitive closure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transitive_closure)<sup>1</sup>).

Some web sites also used [focused crawlers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Focused_crawler), if they try to index only a subset of the web from the first place.

P.S. Some website do neither, and use the service provided by [Google Custom Search API](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/v1/overview)/[Yahoo Boss](http://developer.yahoo.com/search/boss/)/[Bing Deveoper](https://datamarket.azure.com/dataset/5BA839F1-12CE-4CCE-BF57-A49D98D29A44) APIs (for a fee, of course), and use their index, instead of creating one by their own.

P.P.S This is providing a theoretic approach how one can do it, I have no idea how the mentioned website actually works.

---

(1) Due to time issues, the transitive closure is usually not found, but something close enough to it.